# How do you identify exported functions in a Windows static library?

Tags: c++, windows, linker

I'd like to see which functions in a static library will be exported if linked into a dll.  How do I do this?

```
 int foo(int i)
 { return i + 1; }

 __declspec(dllexport) int bar(int i)
 { return i + 1; }
```

`dumpbin /symbols mylib.lib` yields the same information for both functions.

```
00A 00000000 SECT4  notype ()    External     | ?foo@@YAHH@Z (int__cdecl foo(int))
00B 00000020 SECT4  notype ()    External     | ?bar@@YAHH@Z (int __cdecl bar(int))
```

How can I know that `bar()` will be exported but `foo()` will not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Q1)*

> How do you identify exported functions in a Windows static library?

That is one question, and:

*Q2)*

> I'd like to see which functions in a static library will be exported if linked into a dll. How do I do this?

is a different question.

**Q2**

Taking Q2 first: You cannot tell, by any inspection of a static library, which global symbols
defined in it (including DLL exports) will be linked into an arbitrary DLL if that static library is
input to its linkage. To demonstrate:

**foo.c**

```
__declspec(dllexport) int foo(int i) { return i + 1; }
```

**bar.c**

```
__declspec(dllexport) in bar(int i) { return i + 1; }
```

**foomain.c**

```
#include <windows.h>

__declspec(dllexport) int foo(int i);

BOOLEAN WINAPI DllMain( IN HINSTANCE hDllHandle, 
         IN DWORD     nReason, 
         IN LPVOID    Reserved )
{
    return foo(1) == 2;
}
```

**barmain.c**

```
#include <windows.h>

__declspec(dllexport) int bar(int i);

BOOLEAN WINAPI DllMain( IN HINSTANCE hDllHandle,
         IN DWORD     nReason,
         IN LPVOID    Reserved )
{
    return bar(1) == 2;
}
```

Compile all those source files:

```
>cl /c foo.c bar.c foomain.c barmain.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25547 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

foo.c
bar.c
foomain.c
barmain.c
Generating Code...
```

Now make a static library containing `foo.obj` and `bar.obj`:

```
>lib /out:foobar.lib foo.obj bar.obj
Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Next, link a DLL with inputs `foomain.obj` and `foobar.lib`:

```
>link /out:foo.dll /dll foomain.obj foobar.lib
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

   Creating library foo.lib and object foo.exp
```

Lastly, link another DLL with inputs `barmain.obj` and, again, `foobar.lib`

```
>link /out:bar.dll /dll barmain.obj foobar.lib
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

   Creating library bar.lib and object bar.exp
```

Both of the functions, `foo` and `bar`, defined within `foobar.lib`, are declared
`dllexport`. Let's see what symbols are exported by `foo.dll`:

```
>dumpbin /exports foo.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file foo.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for foo.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    FFFFFFFF time date stamp
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           1 number of functions
           1 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001030 foo

  Summary

        2000 .data
        6000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        B000 .text
```

Just `foo`, not `bar`.

And what are the exports of `bar.dll`?

```
>dumpbin /exports bar.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file bar.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for bar.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    FFFFFFFF time date stamp
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           1 number of functions
           1 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001030 bar

  Summary

        2000 .data
        6000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        B000 .text
```

Just `bar`, not `foo`.

Whether `foo` or `bar`, or both, or neither, will be linked from `foobar.lib` into
an executable or DLL depends on what *object files not within static libraries* are also
in the linkage.

The static library `foobar.lib` is simply an archive (in Unix [`ar` archive format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)))
of object files (`foo.o`, `bar.o`) that you can offer to the linker from which to
select the ones it needs, if any, to carry on the linkage of an executable or DLL. The linker
extracts just those object files from the archive and inputs them to the linkage, exactly
as if you had named them individually in the linker commandline and not mentioned the static
library at all.

The object files that the linker will need to extract from a static library are those
that provide definitions for unresolved references that accrue from *other* object files
that must be linked.

So the linkage of `foo.dll` proceeds like this:

- `foomain.obj` is linked because an object file named in the commandline is linked unconditionally.
- The linkage of `foomain.obj` gives rises to an unresolved reference to `foo`.
- So `foobar.lib` is searched for an object file that defines `foo`.
- The archive member `foobar.lib(foo.obj)` is found to provide a definition of `foo`, so it is extracted and linked into `foo.dll`.
- The other archive member `foobar.lib(bar.obj)` provides no definitions for any unresolved references, so it is not extracted or linked.

The linkage:

```
>link /out:foo.dll /dll foomain.obj foobar.lib
```

is *exactly the same as*:

```
>link /out:foo.dll /dll foomain.obj foo.obj
```

And likewise, the linkage:

```
>link /out:bar.dll /dll barmain.obj foobar.lib
```

is exactly the same as:

```
>link /out:bar.dll /dll barmain.obj bar.obj
```

A static library contributes nothing to a linkage except the object files that
are picked out of it, and the ones that are picked out, if any, depend on the
other object files in the linkage. In this light you can see that Q2 amounts to:

*If I have some object files in which are are defined symbols some declared `dllexport`, and some not, how can I tell which of the symbols will be exported from a DLL, given that 0 or more of those object files are linked into it?*

How long is a piece of string? You need to be given the actual linkage of some actual DLL to be able to determine what its DLL exports will be.

**Back to Q1**

In the same light, Q1 amounts to:

*How do you identify exported functions in a Windows object file?*

That *must* be possible, because the linker does it.

We inspected the DLL exports of `foo.dll` by running:

```
>dumpbin /exports foo.dll
```

and it reported `foo`. `dumpbin /exports FILE` is the way we'd usually interrogate
the DLL exports of a `FILE` that is a DLL or program. It shows us the symbols in
the dynamic symbol table of `FILE`.

`dumpbin` knows that a static libary is just a bag of object files. So

```
>dumpbin /symbols foobar.lib
```

shows us the same two symbol tables as:

```
>dumpbin /symbols foo.obj bar.obj
```

i.e.

```
COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 010463CB ABS    notype       Static       | @comp.id
001 80000191 ABS    notype       Static       | @feat.00
002 00000000 SECT1  notype       Static       | .drectve
    Section length   3C, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum 67EAC832
004 00000000 SECT2  notype       Static       | .debug$S
    Section length   6C, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
006 00000000 SECT3  notype       Static       | .text$mn
    Section length    B, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum B38E4E30
008 00000000 SECT3  notype ()    External     | _bar

String Table Size = 0x0 bytes

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 010463CB ABS    notype       Static       | @comp.id
001 80000191 ABS    notype       Static       | @feat.00
002 00000000 SECT1  notype       Static       | .drectve
    Section length   3C, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum 1D7A1E73
004 00000000 SECT2  notype       Static       | .debug$S
    Section length   6C, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
006 00000000 SECT3  notype       Static       | .text$mn
    Section length    B, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum B38E4E30
008 00000000 SECT3  notype ()    External     | _foo

String Table Size = 0x0 bytes
```

Likwise:

```
>dumpbin /exports foobar.lib
```

reports the same DLL exports - namely *none* - as:

```
>dumpbin /exports foo.obj bar.obj
```

And it must be *none* because an object file has no dynamic symbol table.

A dynamic symbol table is generated by the linker. So only files produced by
the linker can possess one. That means a DLL or executable. Not an object file, which is
produced by the compiler and consumed by the linker.

The linker records in the dynamic symbol table of a DLL or executable the
global symbols that are qualified `dllexport` in the object files *that were actually linked*.
Thus, `foo.dll` exports `foo` because `foo` is qualfied as `dllexport` in the archive
member `foobar.lib(foo.obj)` *which was linked* into `foo.dll`. It does not export
`bar`, although `bar` is also qualified `dllexport` in `foobar.lib(bar.obj)`
because that object file was *not* linked into `foo.dll`

So the linker *detects* that `foo` is qualified as `dllexport` in `foo.obj` and
on that basis adds `foo` to the dynamic symbol table of `foo.dll`.

That qualification takes the simple form of a linker directive that the *compiler* embeds
in `foo.obj` instructing the linker to export the symbol `foo` for dynamic linkage.
The compiler emits that linker directive because the source code declares `foo`
with `__declspec(dllexport)`. And the linker will obey that directive, if it links
`foo.obj`, by adding `foo` to the dynamic symbol table. You could build the same `foo.dll`
without using `__declspec(dllexport)` at all in the source code and instead giving
the linker flag `/export:foo` yourself in the linker commandline.

*You* can therefore detect the `dllexport` qualification of `foo` by asking `dumpbin` to show
you the linker directives that the compiler has inscribed in `foo.obj`:

```
>dumpbin /directives foo.obj
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file foo.obj

File Type: COFF OBJECT

   Linker Directives
   -----------------
   /DEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT
   /DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES
   /EXPORT:_foo             <-- This

  Summary

          6C .debug$S
          3C .drectve
           B .text$mn
```

And similarly:

```
>dumpbin /directives bar.obj
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file bar.obj

File Type: COFF OBJECT

   Linker Directives
   -----------------
   /DEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT
   /DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES
   /EXPORT:_bar             <-- And this

  Summary

          6C .debug$S
          3C .drectve
           B .text$mn
```

So:

```
>dumpbin /directives foobar.lib
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file foobar.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

   Linker Directives
   -----------------
   /DEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT
   /DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES
   /EXPORT:_bar

   Linker Directives
   -----------------
   /DEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT
   /DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES
   /EXPORT:_foo

  Summary

          D8 .debug$S
          78 .drectve
          16 .text$mn
```

reports the same two exports as:

```
>dumpbin /directives foo.obj bar.obj
```

and that is the answer to Q1.

Comment: Perhaps "dumpbin /directives foobar.lib" would have been a sufficient answer?  But thanks.